# How can I make a finger splint for a baby?

Tags: hand

My 7 month old son has Camptudactyly, in which some of his fingers do not open all the way.  The specialist who diagnosed him agreed that it would not do any harm to (judiciously) try a homemade splint before his treatment starts in about 6 months.

**How can I make or where can I buy a splint that will either put some gentle opening pressure (or maybe just prevent closing of the hand) on the  on his middle, ring, and pinky fingers of my 7-month old child?**

I've looked around and seen many adult finger splints, thermoplastics, velcro, padded aluminum, stiff medical tape, etc, but the fact that he is a baby complicates things.  Here is a list of considerations:

1. He'll likely only be able to wear the thing while sleeping, so we need to be able to slip it on without waking him.
2. He'll probably try to eat it at some point when we are not watching him, so it needs to be choking-safe and non-toxic.
3. His fingers are small and soft and his hand is chubby and squishy :)